# Read Data from JSON file using d3.js

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I am new to d3.js and I am trying to reproduce the example `B is for breaking links` in [this tutorial](http://www.coppelia.io/2014/07/an-a-to-z-of-extra-features-for-the-d3-force-layout/).

As you can see in the jsfiddle of this example, the data is read from a `<script type="application/json" id="mis">` tag, but what I want is to read it from a different file.

I used the `d3.json()` function as suggested in this [Force-Layout example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045), but when I added the threshold slider which is supposed to break my links, nothing happens.

When I ran the console, it gave me the following error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'splice' of 
undefined
threshold @ index.html:82
onchange @ index.html:101
```

This is my code :

**output.json**

The file `output.json` is in [this link](http://www.mediafire.com/view/0rklzhesd0p3ot9/output.json).

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.node {
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.link {
  stroke: #999;
  stroke-opacity: .6;
}

h3 {
    color: #1ABC9C;
    text-align:center;  
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: "Helvetica";
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var width = 960,
    height = 500;

var color = d3.scale.category20();

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .charge(-120)
    .linkDistance(30)
    .size([width, height]);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var graph = d3.json("output.json", function(error, graph) {
  if (error) throw error;

  graphRec=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(graph));

  force
      .nodes(graph.nodes)
      .links(graph.links)
      .start();

  var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
      .data(graph.links)
    .enter().append("line")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .style("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); });

  var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
      .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("r", 5)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); })
      .call(force.drag);

  node.append("title")
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

  force.on("tick", function() {
    link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
  });
});

//adjust threshold
function threshold(thresh) {
    graph.links.splice(0, graph.links.length);
        for (var i = 0; i < graphRec.links.length; i++) {
            if (graphRec.links[i].value > thresh) {graph.links.push(graphRec.links[i]);}
        }
    restart();
}
//Restart the visualisation after any node and link changes
function restart() {
    link = link.data(graph.links);
    link.exit().remove();
    link.enter().insert("line", ".node").attr("class", "link");
    node = node.data(graph.nodes);
    node.enter().insert("circle", ".cursor").attr("class", "node").attr("r", 5).call(force.drag);
    force.start();
}

</script>

<form>
    <h3> Link threshold 0 <input type="range" id="thersholdSlider" name="points" value = 0 min="0" max="10" onchange="threshold(this.value)"> 10 </h3>
</form>
```

What did I do wrong ? And how can I fix it ?

Thanks!

Comment: try logging graph see what that gives you

Comment: whats ur output.json can you paste that too

Comment: @Cyril I just updated the post with a link to the `output.json` file. I tried to paste it to the post but it is too big.

Comment: @thisOneGuy can you tell me how can I do that? loging graph?

Comment: console.log(graph) just before you use it , in your threshold function ( where i take it the error gets thrown)

Comment: i dont see any issues in loading your graph check the fiddle http://plnkr.co/edit/SqhJmWhUWvEzmODN4s3A?p=preview may be its some loading issue on ur side.

Comment: @Cyril the code you did in the fiddle is similar to mine and it gives the same error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'splice' of undefined`

Comment: @thisOneGuy I just tried it, it gives `Object{}` and it looks empty to me.

Comment: strange i don't see any error and the graph loads up here is proof http://www.clipular.com/c/4708316886859776.png?k=Dt-TbWcMdP7CnYU8scC4yj7atgA tried both on ff and chrome

Comment: it's because youre using the wrong graph variable. You're graph variable you want is inside the other graph variable. d3.json("output.json", function(error, graph) { <<<< that graph you want to use. So set a variable and set it as graph and use that variable later on

Comment: @Cyril the error occures when I add threshold slider

Comment: @thisOneGuy OK I will try that

Answer (score 2):

I could not find any bugs in your code. The only problem I could find is that the variable name graph used twice.

> var **graph** = d3.json("output.json", function(error, **graph**) {
>       ---------------------
>       ---------------------
>   });

**Edit:** Try this code.

```
var graphRec, node, link;
d3.json("output.json", function(error, graph) {
   if (error) throw error;
   graph = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(graph));

   force
      .nodes(graph.nodes)
      .links(graph.links)
      .start();

   graphRec = graph;

   link = svg.selectAll(".link")
      .data(graph.links)
      .enter().append("line")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .style("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); });

   node = svg.selectAll(".node")
      .data(graph.nodes)
      .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("r", 5)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); })
      .call(force.drag);

   ------------------------
   ------------------------
});

//adjust threshold
function threshold(thresh) {
    graphRec.links.splice(0, graphRec.links.length);
        for (var i = 0; i < graphRec.links.length; i++) {
            if (graphRec.links[i].value > thresh) {graphRec.links.push(graphRec.links[i]);}
        }
    restart();
}
//Restart the visualisation after any node and link changes
function restart() {
    link = link.data(graphRec.links);
    link.exit().remove();
    link.enter().insert("line", ".node").attr("class", "link");
    node = node.data(graphRec.nodes);
    node.enter().insert("circle", ".cursor").attr("class", "node").attr("r", 5).call(force.drag);
    force.start();
}
```

Working Code Snippet.

```js
var width = 960,
  height = 500;

var color = d3.scale.category20();

var force = d3.layout.force()
  .charge(-120)
  .linkDistance(30)
  .size([width, height]);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);
   
var graph = {"nodes":[{"name":"DOU,_H.","group":1},{"name":"QUONIAM","group":1},{"name":"DA_SILV","group":1},{"name":"GUIMARA","group":1},{"name":"SOARES_","group":0}],"links":[{"source":1,"target":0,"value":19,"oriented":false,"date":null},{"source":1,"target":2,"value":2,"oriented":false,"date":null},{"source":1,"target":3,"value":1,"oriented":false,"date":null},{"source":1,"target":4,"value":1,"oriented":false,"date":null},{"source":1,"target":3,"value":2,"oriented":false,"date":null}]};

  graph = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(graph));

  force
    .nodes(graph.nodes)
    .links(graph.links)
    .start();

  graphRec = graph;

  var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
    .data(graph.links)
    .enter().append("line")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .style("stroke-width", function(d) {
      return Math.sqrt(d.value);
    });

  var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("r", 5)
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      return color(d.group);
    })
    .call(force.drag);

  node.append("title")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.name;
    });

  force.on("tick", function() {
    link.attr("x1", function(d) {
        return d.source.x;
      })
      .attr("y1", function(d) {
        return d.source.y;
      })
      .attr("x2", function(d) {
        return d.target.x;
      })
      .attr("y2", function(d) {
        return d.target.y;
      });

    node.attr("cx", function(d) {
        return d.x;
      })
      .attr("cy", function(d) {
        return d.y;
      });
  
});

//adjust threshold
function threshold(thresh) {
    graph.links.splice(0, graph.links.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < graphRec.links.length; i++) {
      if (graphRec.links[i].value > thresh) {
        graph.links.push(graphRec.links[i]);
      }
    }
    restart();
  }
  //Restart the visualisation after any node and link changes

function restart() {
  link = link.data(graph.links);
  link.exit().remove();
  link.enter().insert("line", ".node").attr("class", "link");
  node = node.data(graph.nodes);
  node.enter().insert("circle", ".cursor").attr("class", "node").attr("r", 5).call(force.drag);
  force.start();
}
```

```css
.node {
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.link {
  stroke: #999;
  stroke-opacity: .6;
}

h3 {
    color: #1ABC9C;
    text-align:center;  
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: "Helvetica";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <h3> Link threshold 0 <input type="range" id="thersholdSlider" name="points" value = 0 min="0" max="10" onchange="threshold(this.value)"> 10 </h3>
</form>
```

Comment: When I remove `var graph =` it gives me the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: graph is not defined`

Comment: Declare a new variable and assign graph to that variable inside d3.json callback function. Use the new variable inside `threshold` and `restart` functions.

Comment: Since you have a global variable called graphRec with the data, you can also use it instead of graph inside the `threshold` and `restart` functions.

Comment: It gives another error `Uncaught ReferenceError: link is not defined` in the functions `restart` and `threshold`

Comment: This is also because of the variable scope problem. Declare link and node variable outside of d3.json function. Just update the variable value inside the function. (The line `link = link.data(graphRec.links);`, in restart function causes this issue. Since link is out of scope of this function.)

Comment: It seems that we're going the right way :) Now I have no errors but when I move the slider, the graph disappears and the Console shows nothing.

Comment: When you write `graphRec=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(graph));`, a clone of graph object is assigned to graphRec and any further update to this object is not reflected in graphRec. Since graph is an object, you can directly assign the graph value to graphRec like this. `graphRec= graph;`.

Comment: Or try this way. `graph=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(graph)); force.nodes(graph.nodes).links(graph.links).start(); graphRec = graph`. This is necessary because x and y positions are added to the graph object only after the force layout is started.

Comment: Now the graph is showing well at the start but whenever I move the slider, all the links are broken and all the nodes are detached. Even when I get the slider back to `0`, the links are still broken.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102461/discussion-between-user1885868-and-gilsha).